# New-AzureRMVM : Shared Access Signature (SAS) URI is not allowed for property 'osDisk.vhd.uri' with API version 2018-06-01 and higher

Tags: powershell, azure

I have an Virtual Disk (vhd) in an Azure blobstore and wan't to create a new Virtual Machine within Azure. To get this done i created an powershell script with contains the following:

```
#Global Parameters 
$ResourceGroup = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | where {$_. ResourceGroupName -eq "VirtualMachines"}
$VMName = "vmDenodoDatabases"
$Location = "westeurope"
$netWork  =  Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork | where {$_. Name -eq "rg-network"}

Write-Host $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName
#VM Parameter
$vmSize = "Standard_A2"
$BlobLocation = "https://storagedatavault.blob.core.windows.net/vms/Denodo%20Training%20QuickStart%20Virtual%20Machine-disk001.vhd?st=2019-08-24T17%3A12%3A00Z&se=2019-08-25T17%3A12%3A13Z&sp=racwdl&sv=2018-03-28&sr=c&sig=Ke1EC%2FEk%2FwUnnvhNE0grAz7YrXfoObwxzFy%2FBl7Ucdw%3D"

#Network Parameter
$SubnetName = "default"
$InterfaceName = "DenodoDBNic1"

# Create Network Security Group, Subnet and Virtual Network
$NSG = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup
$Subnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork | where {$_.ResourceGroupName -eq "rg-Netwerk"} | Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig


# Create the Interface
#$pip = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name "$VMName-IP" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -AllocationMethod Dynamic

Write-Host $Subnet.Id
#$Interface  = New-AzureRMNetworkInterface -Name $InterfaceName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -SubnetId $Subnet.Id -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id

# VM Details 
Write-Host "VM Config 1"
$VirtualMachine  = New-AzureRMVMConfig -VMName $VMName -VMSize $VMSize # -AvailabilitySetID $AvailabilitySet.Id
Write-Host "VM Config 2"
$VirtualMachine  = Add-AzureRMVMNetworkInterface -VM $VirtualMachine -Id $Interface.Id
Write-Host "VM Config 3"
$VirtualMachine  = Set-AzureRMVMOSDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -Name $VMName -VhdUri $BlobLocation -CreateOption Attach -Linux

# Create the VM in Azure
Write-Host "Create VM"
New-AzureRMVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -VM $VirtualMachine
```

Everything goes fine except the last part in the execution it returns the following output:

```
New-AzureRMVM : Shared Access Signature (SAS) URI is not allowed for property 'osDisk.vhd.uri' with API version 2018-06-01 and higher.
ErrorCode: InvalidParameter
ErrorMessage: Shared Access Signature (SAS) URI is not allowed for property 'osDisk.vhd.uri' with API version 2018-06-01 and higher.
ErrorTarget: osDisk.vhd.uri
StatusCode: 400
ReasonPhrase: Bad Request
OperationID : e71a5aa2-cd0e-4282-9cba-1594e3d2bc6e
At C:\Users\Admin\Documents\PowerShell\CreateAzureVMFromBlob.ps1:37 char:1
+ New-AzureRMVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -Lo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmVM], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand
```

Can you please help me!!

Manny thanks
Erik

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar query discussion in the [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7ba5ac79-a2b9-47c0-a09e-5ec8d0a8bb9c/newazurermvm-shared-access-signature-sas-uri-is-not-allowed-for-property-osdiskvhduri-with?forum=windowsazuredata) link, please refer to the suggestion mentioned that link, kindly let us know if you need any more assistance on this issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The question on MSDN is also not answered. So I like more assistance on this issue!